# Select rows from a table(with row/col spans) to form a new table html js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a table with checkboxes as the first column for selecting the row. Based on my selection I have to form a new table. The problem here is I have tables with row/col span.

Example1:

[image]

In the above table, I'm selecting the 2nd,3rd, and 5th rows. So now my new table should look something like this:

[image]

Example 2:
Given table: Selected rows are 2nd, 3rd and 5th

[image]

Result table:

[image]

Please suggest me a solution to handle this with javascript and jquery

Comment: My suggestion is that you convert the table to a twodimensional array with data where you store spanned cells several times with the same ID or element reference. Then you apply your filter, and then you rebuild your html table from the array, using a rule where for each cell you check if the neighboring cells to the right and/or bottom have the same ID or element reference, and if yes then you convert it to the corresponding spanned cell (and ignore the following cells with the same ID, for example by keeping a set of already-processed cells).

Answer (score 1):

The question was closed a little while ago, but maybe OP is still listening: Here is my answer! Not as short as I would have liked, but it does work. So far only with `rowspan` (and not with `colspan`).

Click on the various checkboxes to see what the script does.

```js
const qs=(s,el=document)=>el.querySelector(s);         // two shorthand 
const qsa=(s,el=document)=>[...el.querySelectorAll(s)];// functions ...
const cols=qs("#source thead tr").children.length;     // no. of columns in source table
const tbl=[...qs("#source tbody").children];tbl.rs=[]; // array of <TR>s
const sels=tbl.map(tr=>qs("input",tr));                // array of checkboxes
const trgt=qs("#target tbody");                        // target TBODY

const res=tbl.map((tr,n)=>{ // extract a full 2D array from source table and store in `res`
  const tds=[], t=[...tr.children].slice(1);
  for (i=1;i<cols;i++){  // for all columns in the header ...
    if (tbl.rs[i]?.r) {  // is there a stored one in the rowspan array rs?
       tds.push(tbl.rs[i].t);
       tbl.rs[i].r-=1;
       if (!tbl.rs[i].r) delete tbl.rs[i];
    } else {             // otherwise: take the next td fron the current table row
       let td=t.shift();
       tds.push(td.innerHTML);
       td.rowSpan>1 && (tbl.rs[i]={r:td.rowSpan-1,t:td.innerHTML}) // save in rs!
    }
  }
  return tds;
 })

// attach a click handler to all checkboxes in the source table:
tbl[0].parentNode.onclick=ev=>{
  if (ev.type==="click" && ev.target.tagName==="INPUT") copyArr2Tbl(res,trgt) }

function copyArr2Tbl(arr,tbl){ // copies the contents of a 2D array to a target tbl (tbody)
 tbl.innerHTML=arr
   .filter((_,i)=>sels[i].checked)
   .map(tr=>"<tr><td>"+tr.join("</td><td>")+"</td></tr>").join("\n");
 for (let i=cols;--i;) applyRowspan(tbl,i);  // and applies rowspan where applicable
}

function applyRowspan(trgt,col){ // applies rowspan to cells of column col having identical content
  let prev=null;
  const tds=qsa("td:nth-child("+col+")",trgt),
        c=tds.map(function(e,i){if (prev!=(prev=e.innerHTML)) return i;}).filter(e=>!isNaN(e));
  c.push(tds.length); // c is an array with indices of unique content in one column 
  for (let i=c.length-2;i>=0;i--) 
  { let j=c[i], n=c[i+1]-j;
    if (n>1) {        // apply rowspan and delete obsolete cells
      tds[j].rowSpan=n;
      tds.slice(j+1,j+n).forEach(td=>td.remove());
    }
  }
}
```

```css
table { border-collapse:collapse }
td   {padding:2px 26px}
```

```html
<table id="source" border="1">
<thead><tr><th>sel</th><th>Head1</th><th>Head2</th><th>Head3</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td>Row1C1</td><td rowspan="3">Row1C2</td><td>Row1C3</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td>Row2C1</td><td>Row2C3</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td>Row3C1</td><td rowspan="3">Row3C3</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td>Row4C1</td><td>Row4C2</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td>Row5C1</td><td>Row1C2</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td>Row3C1</td><td>Row6C2</td><td>Row6C3</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td>Row7C1</td><td>Row7C2</td><td>Row7C3</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<br><br>
<table id="target" border="1"><thead><th>Head1</th><th>Head2</th><th>Head3</th></thead>
<tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: is it possible to update both rowspan and colspan?

Comment: :D "give them an inch and they will ask for a mile" - comes to my mind! You might have noticed that the work so far was not exactly trivial. Doing it in "two dimensions" is of course possible, but also "challenging" ;-). It also opens up new questions: What should happen, if an "L"-shaped area of same-content-cells was found? Should we give preference to "rowspan" or to "colspan"?